# How to install fonts in GNOME without installing the whole GNOME?

Tags: server, gnome, fonts, awesome, chinese

I installed ubuntu server on a laptop, then i installed X window and awesomewm on my laptop.

After i install firefox and open a chinese website, there are full of strange charactor.

On another laptop, I uninstalled GNOME then installed awesomewm, there are no fonts problem.

I think the reason is another laptop's fonts are come from GNOME. How to install gnome fonts on my laptop without install the whole GNOME?

EDIT: [Chinese Wikipedia With Strange Fonts](https://pasteboard.co/JGaVgL0.png)

Comment: Add the fonts to your users' fonts directory, or the fonts to the system directory.  I'm unsure of what fonts you're talking about; you can add individual fonts, or font packages (where `sudo apt install` will install those, or `dpkg` etc)   I don't know your issue, but also wonder if it's unicode or some other issues; so I'd explore the different packages that exist on the one you don't have issues with, and which of those packages is likely to help the system you have issues with.

Answer (score 0):

The packages shipped with the Ubuntu 20.10 desktop are listed here:

https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.10/ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.manifest

The `fonts-` packages in that list are approximately what you asked for. As you see there are quite a few of those.

As regards Chinese the default package on Ubuntu is `fonts-noto-cjk`.